# 3d histogram graphs color for each range in R

Tags: r, graphics, 3d

I would like to know is there any way that I can have different color for different range in the 3D histogram graphs in R.

For example, ı have a table, and ı want to colour the same ranges with yellow. (table[1,1], table[2,2], table[3,3] ... table[12,12] = colour "yellow"; table[1,2],table[1,3], table[2,3],table[2,4] ....= colour "green"; table[2,1],table[3,1],table[8,5].... = colour "red".
 How can ı do this?

My table data;

```
   A     B     C     D    E    F    G  H  I J K L
A  2  7660  1868   673  138   83   13  0  0 0 0 0
B 34 61426 21333  7849 2039 1204  150  3  1 0 1 0
C  8 23539 16409  9646 2309 2088  193  6  2 2 0 0
D  3 12209 12748 12516 3943 4342  547 12  1 1 1 0
E  0  1848  2957  5656 3402 6712 1500 31  0 1 1 0
F  0     3    24   521  637 1798  614  9  2 0 1 0
G  0     0     0   828 1284 4496 2142 44  3 1 1 0
H  0     0     0   195  457 2097 1416 65  0 0 1 1
I  0     0     0     0  161 1327 1355 98  8 3 1 0
J  0     0     0     0   52  559  693 69  8 0 0 1
K  0     0     0     0   40  431  669 97 11 5 0 1
L  0     0     0     0    0    0    0  0  0 0 0 0

hist3D (x = 1:12, y = 1:12, z = table1,bty = "g", phi = 20,
theta = -60,xlab = "Income", ylab = "ModelIncome", zlab = "Counts",
main = "Income&ModelIncome",col = "#0072B2",border = "black", 
shade = 0.8,ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9)
```

Income and Model Income:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to adjust the colors by table indices:

```
table1 <- read.table(header=T, text="   A     B     C     D    E    F    G  H  I J K L
A  2  7660  1868   673  138   83   13  0  0 0 0 0
B 34 61426 21333  7849 2039 1204  150  3  1 0 1 0
C  8 23539 16409  9646 2309 2088  193  6  2 2 0 0
D  3 12209 12748 12516 3943 4342  547 12  1 1 1 0
E  0  1848  2957  5656 3402 6712 1500 31  0 1 1 0
F  0     3    24   521  637 1798  614  9  2 0 1 0
G  0     0     0   828 1284 4496 2142 44  3 1 1 0
H  0     0     0   195  457 2097 1416 65  0 0 1 1
I  0     0     0     0  161 1327 1355 98  8 3 1 0
J  0     0     0     0   52  559  693 69  8 0 0 1
K  0     0     0     0   40  431  669 97 11 5 0 1
L  0     0     0     0    0    0    0  0  0 0 0 0")
table1 <- as.matrix(table1)

library(plot3D)
colvar <- structure(rep(NA, prod(dim(table1))), .Dim =dim(table1), .Dimnames = dimnames(table1))
diag(colvar) <- 1
colvar[2, ] <- 2
colvar[, 3] <- 3

hist3D (x = 1:12, y = 1:12, z = table1,bty = "g", phi = 20,
theta = -60,xlab = "Income", ylab = "ModelIncome", zlab = "Counts",
main = "Income&ModelIncome",col = c("blue", "yellow", "red"),border = "black", 
shade = 0.8,ticktype = "detailed", space = 0.15, d = 2, cex.axis = 1e-9, colvar = colvar)
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to check the answer in order to mark the question as solved, if this is what you were looking for.